# 'bytes' object has no attribute 'condition'

Tags: python

I am trying to stream my Rpi (zero) camera (v2.0) to HTML using cv2.VideoCapture.

However, I am facing a lot of errors and I'm currently stuck on this one as there are no similar issues online currently. Below is my full code (ps this code is from many different sources combined together):

```
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</h1></center>
<center><img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480"></center>
</body>
</html>
"""
class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True


def generate_frames():
    while True:

        ret, frame = camera.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame)
            frame=buffer.tobytes()

        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
                
if __name__=="__main__":
    output = generate_frames()
    output = output.__next__()
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.release()
```

Error Message:

```
192.168.18.17 - - [07/May/2022 11:38:11] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.18.17 - - [07/May/2022 11:38:11] "GET /stream.mjpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
WARNING:root:Removed streaming client ('192.168.18.17', 51120): 'bytes' object has no attribute 'condition'
```

It seems that there is no problem with the server as the page is able to load, however, there is no camera stream available. I believe I have made some errors in my **generate_frames()** function but I don't know where and why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you need to learn about "pdb", python's debugger. then you need to debug your program, meaning to explore what it does. why do you think `output.condition` is a sensible expression? where did you find this code?

Comment: hi @ChristophRackwitz, my code is trying to modify https://randomnerdtutorials.com/video-streaming-with-raspberry-pi-camera/ codes by changing rapicam library to using opencv to get the videocapture from video(0) -> which is also my rapicam. However, I am not sure if I have written the opencv portion correctly for it to be able to upload to the web.

Comment: I have written "output = output.__next()__", as I was facing another error before this currently one,  ‘generator’ object has no attribute ‘next’ and I manage to find a solution to that at  https://www.tutorialexample.com/fix-python-yield-attributeerror-generator-object-has-no-attribute-next-python-tutorial/